# No named parameter with the name 'floatingLabelStyle'. in flutter project

Tags: flutter

My flutter project was all fine until suddenly this error is appearing when i try to run the project - `flutter run`.

```
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pinput-1.2.2/lib/pin_put/pin_put_state.dart:35:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'floatingLabelStyle'.
      floatingLabelStyle: hiddenTextStyle,                              
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_decorator.dart:2504:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const InputDecoration({                                               
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                 
                                                                        
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* Where:                                                                
Script '/Users/bright/Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 991
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.              
> Process 'command '/Users/bright/Desktop/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
                                                                        
* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                        
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Ive tried a solution that suggested adding `flutter_svg` as a dependency but that did not work.

This is how i've declared my input decoration

```
static InputDecoration textInputDeco = InputDecoration(
  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.orange,)
  ),
  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.orangeAccent)
  ),
  filled: true,
  fillColor: Colors.grey[900],
  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500]),
  labelStyle:  TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500]),
  helperStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),

);
```

**flutter doctor**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287 darwin-x64, locale en-KE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ! Xcode 11.5.0 out of date (12.0.1 is recommended).
      Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: Can you share the code snippet of your inputdecoration?

Comment: @Bright Can you tell where you have added floatingLabelStyle in your code?

Comment: You need to define floatingLabelStyle inside your textInputDeco or alternatively use the copywith method on it and define it there. Of course, you can also remove the floatingLabelStyle.

Comment: There is no parameter named floatingLabelStyle.

Comment: @Pranav. I have not used it anywhere. Thats why in the error its eminent that its from flutter, not my code.

Comment: @Bright try adding this line- `floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),`